# Automatic serialization with Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, serialization, xml-serialization

Is there any way to store data in the table kind of this:

[image]

Inside `SettingsModel` column, which is defined in `Linq-to-Sql` like this:

[image]

And also with `DataContext` option turned to the:

[image]

With the class SettingsModel defined like this:

```cs
namespace ElQueue.DataClasses
{
    [DataContract]
    public sealed class SettingsModel
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int[] VideoMediaData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This way? ...

```cs
using (SomeDataContext dataContext = new SomeDataContext())
{
    SettingsModel m = new SettingsModel();
    m.VideoMediaData = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    dataContext.MainTableSettings.InsertOnSubmit(new MainTableSetting() { SettingsModel = m });
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}

using (SomeDataContext dataContext = new SomeDataContext())
{
    var r = dataContext.MainTableSettings.Single();
}
```

You see, the code above doesnt work correctly, it is throwing exception which says that it cannot convert string to `MainTableSetting` which means that either it can not save all the serialized data or that plus cannot deserialize it back.

I need some advices how to point this `Linq-to-Sql` to actually do serialization (and vice versa) when I access the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Although you can map XElement and XDocument to SQL Server as shown in the Type Mapping Run Time Behavior Matrix, the System.Data.Linq.DataContext.CreateDatabase method has **no default SQL Server type mapping** for these types.
>
> If a class implements **Parse()** and **ToString()**, you can map the object to any SQL text type (CHAR, NCHAR, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, TEXT, NTEXT, XML). The object is stored in the database by sending the value returned by **ToString()** to the mapped database column. The object is reconstructed by invoking **Parse()** on the string returned by the database.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx#TextMapping

```
public sealed class SettingsModel
{
    // ...

    public static SettingsModel Parse(string source)
    {
        SettingsModel res;

        // Deserialise the object

        return res;
    }
}
```